# Using React-Hooks, how do I prevent a component created from Array.map from re-rendering if one of it's siblings changes state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've created a grid of components using array.map. Using `console.log` I'm able to see that each component is re-rendering whenever one of the components is changing state. When I have a grid of 50x50, this becomes noticeably slow.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Cell({ cell, cellState, updateBoard }) {

  console.log('cell rendered')

  const CellStyle = {
    display: 'inline-block',
    width: '10px',
    height: '10px',
    border: '1px green solid',
    background: cellState ? 'green' : 'purple'
  };

  function handleClick(e) {
    updateBoard(cell, !cellState)
  }

  return (
    <span
      style={CellStyle}
      onClick={handleClick}
    />
  )
}

function App() {

  console.log('board rendered')

  const initialState = new Array(10).fill().map(() => new Array(10).fill(false));

  let [board, setBoard] = useState(initialState);

  function updateBoard(cell, nextState) {
    let tempBoard = [...board];
    tempBoard[cell[0]][cell[1]] = nextState;
    setBoard(tempBoard)
  }

  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'inline-block' }}>
      {board.map((v, i, a) => {
        return (
          <div
            key={`Row${i}`}
            style={{ height: '12px' }}
          >
            {v.map((w, j) =>
              <Cell
                key={`${i}-${j}`}
                cell={[i, j]}
                cellState={board[i][j]}
                updateBoard={updateBoard}
              />
            )}
          </div>
        )
      }
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

When I click on one of the components, I want the parent state to update, and the clicked component to update and re-render. Since the rest of the components aren't changed, I don't want the other components to re-render. How do I accomplish this using React-Hooks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is few things that would greatly improve performance:

1. using `memo()`

```
const MemoizedCell = memo(Cell);
/*...*/
<MemoizedCell 
  /*...*/
/>
```

2. not passing new references to `<Cell />` every time

You are passing `cell={[i, j]}` - it creates **new Array every time you invoke it(!)** that means that props of Cells has been changed - why would it not render again then?

Same with passing `updateBoard={updateBoard}` - you are creating new function every time `<App />` renders. You need to memorize it and use old state in function.

```
  const updateBoard = useCallback(
    (cell, nextState) => {
      setBoard(oldBoard => {
        let tempBoard = [...oldBoard];
        tempBoard[cell[0]][cell[1]] = nextState;
        return tempBoard;
      });
    },
    [setBoard]
  );
```

3. you are creating `initialState` every render - move it above (outside) `<App />` or create it inside `useState` as function (and use `const` instead of `let` here).

```
const [board, setBoard] = useState(() =>
  new Array(10).fill().map(() => new Array(10).fill(false))
);
```

---

final solution:

```
import React, { useState, memo, useCallback } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function Cell({ i, j, cellState, updateBoard }) {
  console.log(`cell ${i}, ${j} rendered`);

  const CellStyle = {
    display: "inline-block",
    width: "10px",
    height: "10px",
    border: "1px green solid",
    background: cellState ? "green" : "purple"
  };

  function handleClick(e) {
    updateBoard([i, j], !cellState);
  }

  return <span style={CellStyle} onClick={handleClick} />;
}

const MemoizedCell = memo(Cell);

function App() {
  console.log("board rendered");

  const [board, setBoard] = useState(() =>
    new Array(10).fill().map(() => new Array(10).fill(false))
  );

  const updateBoard = useCallback(
    (cell, nextState) => {
      setBoard(oldBoard => {
        let tempBoard = [...oldBoard];
        tempBoard[cell[0]][cell[1]] = nextState;
        return tempBoard;
      });
    },
    [setBoard]
  );

  return (
    <div style={{ display: "inline-block" }}>
      {board.map((v, i, a) => {
        return (
          <div key={`Row${i}`} style={{ height: "12px" }}>
            {v.map((w, j) => (
              <MemoizedCell
                key={`${i}-${j}`}
                i={i}
                j={j}
                cellState={board[i][j]}
                updateBoard={updateBoard}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: do you also know how to get rid of the eslint error complaining about the missing dependency `board` ('react-hooks/exhaustive-deps')

Comment: @hyde you can add `board` as `[board, setBoard]` in `const updateBoard`

Comment: @hyde But if you wanna do that, you need to use function in `setBoard`. I updated my answer - now it should validate correctly in `eslint`

Comment: This really helps clear up a lot of confusion regarding useCallback and useMemo for increased performance.